# JSON. A reference deserializes to null

Tags: json, ref

I am using Newtonsoft.json. I can't understand result of a deserialization. Bulletin.PageList is being filled ok. But Page of Question which is referencing to element of PageList is always null. In the JsonSerializerSettings I specified PreserveReferencesHandling.All but it didn't help. Could you help to resolve the problem of null of Page? Thank you

```
JSON structure:

"Bulletins": [
        {
            "$id": "46b5efa80fe644d7bd525e2c30f5df8a",
            "$type": "Bulletin",
            "JSONNETTYPE": "Bulletin",
            "PagesList": [
                {
                    "id": "4ed13d727cd144d1acf1e0c9bc273245",
                    "JSONNETTYPE": "PageView",
                    "Number": 1,
                    "Id": "1a2b8ed4249948e194b396c46a5d1eeb",
                    "UiId": "4ed13d727cd144d1acf1e0c9bc273245"
                }
            ],
            "AgendaQuestions": [
                {
                    "$id": "eceb6fe6c74a40d59f0673b76bd6dbb3",
                    "$type": "QSimple",
                    "Page": {
                        "$ref": "46b5efa80fe644d7bd525e2c30f5df8a#PagesList.0"
                    }
                }
             ]
}]
```

C# structure:

```
public class Bulletin
    {        
        public Bulletin()
        {                        
        }

        public string Dbid { get; set; }

        public List<PageView> PagesList;

        public List<Question> AgendaQuestions;
  }

public abstract class Question
    {
        protected Question(int number, string customNumberLabel = null)
        {
            Number = number;
            CustomNumberLabel = customNumberLabel;
        }

        public int Number { get; set; }

        public string CustomNumberLabel { get; set; }

        public PageView Page { get; set; }    
}

public class PageView
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }    
        public string Id { get; set; }    
        public int BulletinNumber { get; set; }    
        public PageView()
        {                
        }       
    }
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{ PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using dojox.json.ref library. If I set __id for Page, references to elements of PagesList will become direct, not complex (like 46b5efa80fe644d7bd525e2c30f5df8a#PagesList.0), and Page is filled.